# BottomNavigationView: How to remove hypheanted labels

Tags: android, android-bottom-nav-view

Implementing a 5-item BottomNavigationView -with the labels always shown- I'm using the following approach:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

Unfortunately, the result hyphenates words when active, as shown in the picture:

[image: Hyphenated active label]

I tried setting different styles for the label's active text:

```
app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/text_navigation_active_labels"
```

-- styles.xml --

```
<style name="text_navigation_active_labels">
    <item name="android:breakStrategy">simple</item>
    <item name="android:hyphenationFrequency">none</item>
</style>
```

But the result is exactly the same (whether I only use break strategy, hyphenationFrequency or both). I'm currently testing it on an API 27 physical phone.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post an image directly, as it won't allow me due to reputation

Comment: I don't know about the others, but I just adjust the height and width manually in the  XML design.  Giving it more spaces (padding manually)

Comment: @AngusTay How? I've only found how to change text sizes and BottomNavigation height

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As 5 items might be a lot of space, it is necessary to compromise text size. In order to fix it, adding a custom style to the BottomNavigationView text gets the job done:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        ...
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/navTextActive"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/navTextInactive"/>
```

on styles.xml:

```
<style name="navTextInactive">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>

<style name="navTextActive">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Result:

[image: FixedNavBar]

Comment: Why it show "attribute :itemTextAppearanceActive not found" in my fragment layout?

Comment: @quangkid you need to add  android:theme="@style/MaterialBaseTheme"
to your view xml and then add    <style name="MaterialBaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"/>
to your style file , also add     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
 to your build.gradle