# Keep active item label font size the same as other labels in BottomNavigationView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The active item label in the BottomNavigationView gets hyphenated on Android. This happens because the font size of active label is increased. I want it to behave similar to iOS navbar where the active item label size doesn't differ from other labels. 
I followed this
[tutorial](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-fully-customize-bottom-tabs-on-android-turn-off-shifting/) to get to this point.
[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZATs.png)

I found solution for Android native [How to remove hypheanted labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142826/bottomnavigationview-how-to-remove-hypheanted-labels), but I don't know how to use it with Xamarin Forms.

I have tried setting ItemTextAppearanceActive:

```
public class NoShiftEffect : PlatformEffect {
    protected override void OnAttached() {
        if (!(Container.GetChildAt(0) is ViewGroup layout)) {
            return;
        }

        if (!(layout.GetChildAt(1) is BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView)) {
            return;
        }

        bottomNavigationView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityLabeled;

        // How to set this?
        bottomNavigationView.ItemTextAppearanceActive = 5;
    }

    protected override void OnDetached() {
    }
}
```

Any ideas where to set that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in tabpage renderer:

```
public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Element != null)
        {
            var bottomNavigationView = (GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout).GetChildAt(1) as BottomNavigationView;
            var bottomNavMenuView = bottomNavigationView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;
            for (var i = 0; i < Element.Children.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = bottomNavMenuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                var itemTitle = item.GetChildAt(1);
                var smallTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(0));
                var largeTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(1));                    
                smallTextView.TextSize = 5f;
                largeTextView.TextSize = 5f;
                smallTextView.Ellipsize = Android.Text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;
                largeTextView.Ellipsize = Android.Text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

You can set the font of label in tabbed by using Custom Renderer

```
public class StyledTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    private TabLayout tabLayout = null;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        this.tabLayout = (TabLayout)this.GetChildAt(1);


        changeTabsFont();
    }


    private void changeTabsFont()
    {
        //Typeface font = 
        Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/" + Constants.FontStyle);
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)tabLayout.GetChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.ChildCount;
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++)
        {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup)vg.GetChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.ChildCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++)
            {
                Android.Views.View tabViewChild = vgTab.GetChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild is TextView)
                {
                    //((TextView)tabViewChild).Typeface = font;
                    ((TextView)tabViewChild).TextSize = 6;  // set font size here !!!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Solution 2:

You can install the package Naxam.BottomTabbedPage from nuget.

For more details you can check [here](https://github.com/NAXAM/bottomtabbedpage-xamarin-forms) .